# AngularJS access JSON Object returned from $http.get

Tags: angularjs, json

I try to access to json object generated by google api.

```
function getAvengers() {
    return $http.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA')
        .then(getAvengersComplete)
        .catch(getAvengersFailed);

    function getAvengersComplete(response) {
        return response.data;
    }

    function getAvengersFailed(error) {
        console.log('XHR Failed for getAvengers.' + error.data);
    }
}
TestCtrl.dataTest = dataservice.getAvengers();
console.log(TestCtrl.dataTest.status);
```

Log generate undefined.
Could you help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As `getAvengers` returns with a promise, you cannot use it's result as an immediate value, but you can subscribe to it's resolution. See a [promise tutorial](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/) for more details.

```
function getAvengers() {
    return $http.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA')
        .then(getAvengersComplete)
        .catch(getAvengersFailed);

    function getAvengersComplete(response) {
        return response.data;
    }

    function getAvengersFailed(error) {
        console.log('XHR Failed for getAvengers.' + error.data);
    }
}
TestCtrl.dataTest = null;
dataservice.getAvengers().then(function(data) {
  TestCtrl.dataTest = data;
  console.log(TestCtrl.dataTest.status);  
});
```

Comment: even though it works, This seems to be legacy code. Write a separate service and DI in your controller.

Comment: @Raj I think he has separate components, as he is referencing the getAvengers function through a dataservice variable. I think he has DI but only copied the relevant code.

Comment: @EthanHunt You are very welcome. If you found my answer helpful you can even mark it accepted, so the question gets closed.